# How to combine multiple listeners (step, read, process, write and skip) in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

The aim of this operation is to track the lines or items that are being read/processed/written in a spring batch job with multiple steps.

I have created a listener that implements these interfaces : `StepExecutionListener, SkipPolicy, ItemReadListener, ItemProcessListener, ItemWriteListener`

```java
@Component
public class GenericListener implements StepExecutionListener, SkipPolicy, ItemReadListener, ItemProcessListener, ItemWriteListener {
    private Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
    private JobExecution jobExecution;
    private int numeroProcess = 0;
    private int currentReadIndex = 0;
    private int currentProcessIndex = 0;
    private int currentWriteIndex = 0;

    @Override
    public void beforeRead() throws Exception {
        log.info(String.format("[read][line : %s]", currentReadIndex));
        currentReadIndex++;
    }
    @Override
    public void afterRead (Object o) throws Exception {
        log.info("Ligne correct");
    }
    @Override
    public void onReadError (Exception e) throws Exception {
        jobExecution.stop();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkip (Throwable throwable, int i) throws SkipLimitExceededException {
        String err = String.format("Erreur a la ligne %s | message %s | cause %s | stacktrace %s", numeroProcess, throwable.getMessage(), throwable.getCause().getMessage(), throwable.getCause().getStackTrace());
        log.error(err);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeProcess (Object o) {
        log.debug(String .format("[process:%s][%s][Object:%s]", numeroProcess++, o.getClass(), o.toString()));
        currentProcessIndex++;
    }
    @Override
    public void afterProcess (Object o, Object o2) { }
    @Override
    public void onProcessError (Object o, Exception e) {
        String err = String.format("[ProcessError at %s][Object %s][Exception %s][Trace %s]", currentProcessIndex, o.toString(), e.getMessage(), e.getStackTrace());
        log.error(err);
        jobExecution.stop();
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeWrite (List list) {
        log.info(String .format("[write][chunk number:%s][current chunk size %s]", currentWriteIndex, list != null ? list.size() : 0));
        currentWriteIndex++;
    }
    @Override
    public void afterWrite (List list) { }
    @Override
    public void onWriteError (Exception e, List list) {
        jobExecution.stop();
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();
        currentReadIndex = 0;
        currentProcessIndex = 0;
        currentWriteIndex = 0;
    }
    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The job definition (`CustomJobListener` is a simple class that extends `JobExecutionListenerSupport`)

```java
public class BatchConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Bean
    public Job job(CustomJobListener listener,
                     @Qualifier("step1") Step step1,
                     @Qualifier("step2") Step step2,
                     @Qualifier("step3") Step step3) {
        return jobs.get("SimpleJobName")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .preventRestart()
                .listener(listener)
                .start(step1)
                .next(step2)
                .next(step3)
                .build();
    }
}
```

The step definition (all three steps have the same definition, only the read/processor/writer changes)

```java
@Component
public class StepControleFormat {
    @Autowired
    private StepOneReader reader;
    @Autowired
    private StepOneProcessor processor;
    @Autowired
    private StepOneWriter writer;
    @Autowired
    private ConfigAccess configAccess;
    @Autowired
    private GenericListener listener;
    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    @JobScope
    @Qualifier("step1")
    public Step stepOne() throws StepException {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<StepOneInput, StepOneOutput>chunk(configAccess.getChunkSize())
                .listener((ItemProcessListener<? super StepOneInput, ? super StepOneOutput>) listener)
                .faultTolerant()
                .skipPolicy(listener)
                .reader(reader.read())
                .processor(processor.compose())
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that methods `beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution)` and `afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution)` are not fired, but all other methods in `GenericListener` are correctly fired when their respective events occur.

I tried using `listener((StepExecutionListener)listener)` instead of `listener((ItemProcessListener<? super StepOneInput, ? super StepOneOutput>) listener)` but the latter returns `AbstractTaskletStepBuiler` and then I cant use `reader`, `processor` or `writer`.

**Update** : My spring boot version is : v1.5.9.RELEASE

Comment: Do the call to the listener with the `StepExecutionListener` cast after you have set the reader/processor/writer.

Comment: @MichaelMinella I did but it generates a compiler error `Cannot resolve method 'build()'` after `listener((StepExecutionListener)listener)`.

Comment: What version of Spring Batch are you using?  I confirmed that this compiles fine: https://gist.github.com/mminella/3437f89aa6ca85c6f94bd7772ed498a2

Comment: @MichaelMinella I updated my question and answered it (answer below), however there's something in my answer that still is confusing, so if you could help with that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it thanks to Michael Minella's hint :

```java
@Bean
@JobScope
@Qualifier("step1")
public Step stepOne() throws StepException {
    SimpleStepBuilder<StepOneInput, StepOneOutput> builder = stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<StepOneInput, StepOneOutput>chunk(configAccess.getChunkSize())
            // setting up listener for Read/Process/Write
            .listener((ItemProcessListener<? super StepOneInput, ? super StepOneOutput>) listener)
            .faultTolerant()
            // setting up listener for skipPolicy
            .skipPolicy(listener)
            .reader(reader.read())
            .processor(processor.compose())
            .writer(writer);

    // for step execution listener
    builder.listener((StepExecutionListener)listener);

    return builder.build();
}
```

The last called `listener` method `public B listener(StepExecutionListener listener)` from `StepBuilderHelper<B extends StepBuilderHelper<B>>` returns a `StepBuilderHelper` that doesn't contain a definition for a `build()` method. So the solution was to split up the step build definition.

What I don't understand is : although the `writer` method is returning a `SimpleStepBuilder<I, O>` which contains a definition for this method `public SimpleStepBuilder listener(Object listener)`, the compiler/IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) is calling `public B listener(StepExecutionListener listener)` from `StepBuilderHelper<B extends StepBuilderHelper<B>>`. If anyone could help explain this behaviour.

Moreover, finding a way to hookup all listeners in one call using `public SimpleStepBuilder listener(Object listener)` from `SimpleStepBuilder` would be very interesting.

Comment: Thanks for posting this reply.  This was really useful and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Additional Step Listeners can be added as follows.

```
@Bean(name = STEP1)
public Step rpcbcStep() {
    
    SimpleStepBuilder<Employee, Employee> builder = stepBuilderFactory.get(STEP1).<Employee, Employee>chunk(100)
            .reader(step1BackgroundReader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer());
            
    builder.listener(step1BackgroundStepListener)
    builder.listener(step1BackgroundStepListener2);
    // add any other listeners needed
    
    return builder.build();
}
```